# Type of instance in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, types

I came across this piece of code, and I am surprised that it adds an element to the list.

Here's the code:

```
class Wrapper:
    def __init__(self, object):
        self.wrapped = object
    def __getattr__(self,attrname):
        print('Trace: '+attrname)
        return getattr(self.wrapped,attrname)

X = Wrapper([1,2,3])
X.append(4)
print(X.wrapped)
```

I am surprised because if I run `type(X)`, I get `__main__.Wrapper`, which makes sense because `X` is an object of class `Wrapper`. Hence, I am unsure why `X.append` adds to the list in the attribute `wrapped` directly. After all, the type of `X` isn't `list` but `Wrapper.`

Shouldn't the call have been `X.wrapped.append(4)`? This works as well.

I am a beginner, and this might be a basic question. I'd appreciate any thoughts, and thanks for any help.

---

This code was adopted from Mark Lutz's book. I am using Anaconda 3.6 distribution

Comment: The existing call is `X.__getattr__('append')(4)`.

Comment: Firstly, `Object` is a built-in name. Don't use it as your variable names. Secondly, It's because `self.wrapped` is a list and `__getattr__` is calling the `list`'s `append` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This class is just adding a print statement before the original attribute of the object is accessed.

To understand how this works, you have to understand a bit about what `__getattr__` does. The documentation for these methods is under the [data model section](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html) of the Python manual:

> Called when the default attribute access fails with an `AttributeError`
>   (either `__getattribute__()` raises an `AttributeError` because name is
>   not an instance attribute or an attribute in the class tree for self;
>   or `__get__()` of a name property raises `AttributeError`). This method
>   should either return the (computed) attribute value or raise an
>   `AttributeError` exception.

The `.` (dot) operator is really a search or lookup operator, when you write a statement like this:

```
foo.append(x)
```

You and I understand this to mean "call the append method of the foo object, with the argument x" - Python is trying to search for an attribute "append" on the foo object, then trying to call it with an argument of *x*.

In the custom object, we don't have an `append` attribute, which triggers the `__getattr__` call.

We then intercept this call to `__getattr__`, print out a debug statement, and then pass on this call to the actual object (a reference to it is in `self.wrapped`).

In short, we are saying - hey - we understand that our wrapper object doesn't have this property, but *try and see if the wrapped object does*, by calling its `__getattr__` instead.

This concept of passing along the call up the chain allows flexibility in that we mimic what the original (wrapped) object would do - making our wrapper very generic. It would work even if you passed in a string or any other Python object.

Answer (score 0):

The [`__getattr__`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/reference/datamodel.html?highlight=__getattr__#customizing-attribute-access) is an operator overload [magic method](https://dbader.org/blog/python-dunder-methods) for the [attribute reference `.` operator](https://docs.python.org/3.5/reference/expressions.html?highlight=attribute%20reference#operator-precedence). There are several other ways to do this, like [descriptors](https://docs.python.org/3.5/howto/descriptor.html) for single attributes or `__getattribute__` that overrides even existing attributes.